# test with enzyme a react component with context: return an empty object

Tags: testing, reactjs, mocha.js, enzyme

I'm trying to execute a dummy test with enzyme over a component. the test is about to check the context. even though I'm writing the same code as enzyme's documentation the context is always empty.

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import Overlay from '../../../../app/components/Overlay/Overlay';


describe('<Overlay />', () => {
  it.only('return a context', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Overlay />, { context: { foo: 10 } });
    console.log(wrapper.context());
    // expect(wrapper.context().foo).to.equal(10);
  });
})
```

the test's output is:

```
<Overlay />
{}
✓ return a context
```

where am I wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Since the details of `Overlay` component is not given, I assume the context is not used in it (pls check `childContextTypes` and `getChildContext` are defined properly)

For example, refer the explanation for contexts in react [documents](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html#passing-info-automatically-through-a-tree)

I have taken the same example to enable the test,

```
import React from 'react';

export default  class Button extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <button style={{ background: this.context.color }}>
        {this.props.children}
      </button>
    );
  }
}

Button.contextTypes = {
  color: React.PropTypes.string,
};

class Message extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.text} <Button>Delete</Button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class MessageList extends React.Component {
  getChildContext() {
    return { color: 'purple' };
  }

  render() {
    const children = this.props.messages.map((message) =>
      <Message text={message.text} />
    );
    return <div>{children}</div>;
  }
}

MessageList.childContextTypes = {
  color: React.PropTypes.string,
};
```

I've created the test for `Button` component as below,

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import { expect } from 'chai';
import Button from '../../src/components/SampleComp';

describe.only('<Button />', () => {
  it('assert for context', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(
      <Button />,
      { context: { color: 'red' } }
    );
    expect(wrapper.context().color).to.equal('red');
    expect(wrapper.context('color')).to.equal('red');
  });
});
```

> ```
>  <Button />
>     ✓ assert for context
>
>
>   1 passing (214ms)
> ```

This will assert it correctly.